# Error creating bean with name 'imagePropertiesController': Unsatisfied dependency...Not a managed type: class com.example.imagequery.imageProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

Here is the entire error copied below:

```
Error creating bean with name 'imagePropertiesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ImageService': Error creating bean with name 'imageService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ImageRepository': Error creating bean with name 'imageRepository' defined in com.example.imagequery.imageRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ImageQueryApplication: Not a managed type: class com.example.imagequery.imageProperties
```

I am attempting to run this spring boot api and am running into this error. I have tried any combination of entity and component scan to directly identify the Entity class to the application. None of that has worked so i'm looking for another way to explicitly define the entity class. Is there an issue with my jpx use of entity annotation? I tried using jakarta as well and just had a different error. Any guidance is appreciated. I will copy the stack trace in if requested, I am leaving it out for now due to the length of this question.

EDIT:
Another issue I've seen commonly brought with this issue is to do with the file structure, all of these files are in the same folder and path (com.example.imagequery)

Here is what my entity class looks like:

```
package com.example.imagequery;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

import javax.persistence.*;
//Entity Model Class
@Entity
@Table(name = "imageProperties")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.imagequery.imageProperties")
public class imageProperties {
    private int id;
    private String imageName;

    public imageProperties(){
    }

    public imageProperties(int id, String imageName){
        this.id = id;
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


}
```

Here is my application class:

```
package com.example.imagequery;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.*")
@EntityScan("com.example.imagequery.imageProperties")
public class ImageQueryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ImageQueryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my service class:

```
package com.example.imagequery;
import com.example.imagequery.imageProperties;
import com.example.imagequery.imageRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
@Service
@Transactional
public class imageService {
    @Autowired
    private imageRepository ImageRepository;
    public List<imageProperties> listAllImages(){
        return ImageRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void saveImage(imageProperties ImageProperties){
        ImageRepository.save(ImageProperties);
    }

    public imageProperties getImage(Integer id){
        return ImageRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
/*
    public void getImageByObject(String object){
        return ImageRepository
    }
    */
}
```

Here is my repository class:

```
//JPA Data repository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.example.imagequery.imageProperties;

public interface imageRepository extends JpaRepository<imageProperties, Integer>{
}
```

...and here is my controller class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/imageProperties")
public class imagePropertiesController {
    @Autowired
    imageService ImageService;

    @GetMapping("")
    public List<imageProperties> list() {
        return ImageService.listAllImages();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<imageProperties> get(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        try {
            imageProperties ImageProperties = ImageService.getImage(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<imageProperties>(ImageProperties, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<imageProperties>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void add(@RequestBody imageProperties ImageProperties) {
        ImageService.saveImage(ImageProperties);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me guess using Spring Boot 3.x? Remove the `persistence-api` dependency you choose to add. Fix compilation issues `javax` -> `jakarta`, ditch the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` and restart your application. The error you get with the `jakarta` packates is the one to fix using `javax` packages isn't the solution.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. I gave this a shot and was seeing some other errors and worked through those and now service is running. I'm not sure why I am using jpx instead of jakarta, I believe the instructions i'm following told me to do so. Is there any reason I should use jakarta instead of jpa for spring boot 3.x.x?

Comment: Jakarta is JPA. Spring Boot before 3.x was JavaEE since Spring Boot 3 it is JakartaEE. Problem is most tutorials out there are outdated.